# Check matches between two data frame whatever the row with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frame such as :

```
>>> df1

query   target     
A:1     AZ     
B:4     AZ  
C:5     AZ    
D:1     AZ  

>>> df2

query   target
B:6     AZ
C:5     AZ
D:1     AZ
A:1     AZ
```

And the idea is simply to check if the values present in the `df1['query']` are present in the `df2['query']` as well, whatever the order of the row and add a new column the df1 and get:

```
>>> df1

query   target    new_col 
A:1     AZ        present
B:4     AZ        Not_present
C:5     AZ        present
D:1     AZ        present
```

I tried : `df1["new_col"] = df2.apply(lambda row: "present" if row[0] == df1["query"][row.name] else "Not_present", axis = 1)`

but it only check match by rows.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT

What if know I have to compare 3 data frames with the df1

Here is the new exemple:

```
df1 

query
A1
A2
B3
B5
B6
B7
C8
C9

df2

query target
C9    type2
Z6    type2

df3
query target
C10   type3
B6    type3

df4
query target
A1    type4
K9    type1
```

and I will do a loop such as :

```
for df in dataframes: 
   df1['new_col'] = np.where(blast['query'].isin(df['query']), 'Present', 'Not_absent')
```

the issue is that it will override each time the column df1['New_col']

At the end I should get :

```
df1 

    query   new_col
    A1      present_type4
    A2.     not_present
    B3.     not_present
    B5.     not_present
    B6.     present_type3
    B7.     not_present
    C8.     not_present
    C9.     present_type2
```

Edit for `jezrael` :

In order to open my data frames, I have a `file.txt` file such as:

```
Species1
Species2
Species3
```

It helps to call the wright path link where a data frame is for exemple:

```
/admin/user/project/Species1/dataframe.txt etc
```

so I juste call them to create the df such as :

```
for i in file.txt:
 df = open("/admin/user/project/"+i+"/dataframe.txt","r")
```

Then I have as I said above to find matches between all these data frame and one big data frame `(df1)`.

By doing:

```
values=[]
for names in file.txt:
    values.append("/admin/user/project/"+i+"/dataframe.txt") 

for names file.txt:
    keys.append(names)

dicts = {}
for i in keys:
        dicts[i] = values[i]
d = {}
for i in range(len(keys)):
    d[i]=None

for i in range(len(keys)):
    d[keys[i]] = d.pop(i)

for (k,v), i in zip( d.items(),values):
    d[k] = i
```

I succeed to get something as you shown me:

but the values are the path to open for the data frames:

```
>>> d
{'Species1': '/admin/user/project/Species1/dataframe.txt', 'Species2': '/admin/user/project/Species2/dataframe.txt', 'Species3': '/admin/user/project/Species3/dataframe.txt'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1['new_col'] = np.where(df1['query'].isin(df2['query']), 'present', 'Not_present')
print (df1)
  query target      new_col
0   A:1     AZ      present
1   B:4     AZ  Not_present
2   C:5     AZ      present
3   D:1     AZ      present
```

EDIT:

```
d = {'type2':df2, 'type3':df3, 'type4':df4}
df1['new_col'] = 'not_present'
for k, v in d.items(): 
   df1.loc[df1['query'].isin(v['query']), 'new_col'] = 'Present_{}'.format(k)

print (df1)
  query        new_col
0    A1  Present_type4
1    A2    not_present
2    B3    not_present
3    B5    not_present
4    B6  Present_type3
5    B7    not_present
6    C8    not_present
7    C9  Present_type2
```

EDIT: You can in loop create DataFrame and pass to `isin`:

```
d = {'Species1': '/admin/user/project/Species1/dataframe.txt', 'Species2': '/admin/user/project/Species2/dataframe.txt', 'Species3': '/admin/user/project/Species3/dataframe.txt'}
```

---

```
df1['new_col'] = 'not_present'
for k, v in d.items(): 
    df = pd.read_csv(v)
    df1.loc[df1['query'].isin(df['query']), 'new_col'] = 'Present_{}'.format(k)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, It works very well. I just realized that in fact I will have to do it for several data frames. I just updated the post explain what is it really about. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @chippycentra - You can create dictionary of DataFrames, loops by thems and overwrite column if match condition. Please check edited answer.

Comment: Thanks but what if I have over 100 dataframes? I do not know how to create a dict since I open the file.txt containing the df with a list of names such as: `list=(species1,species2,specieq3...)` and for i in list: `df = open("/path1/path2/"+i+"/path3","r")` so the `df` changes at each iteration.

Comment: @chippycentra - Can you add your code with create DataFrames in loop to question, because bad formating in comments?

Answer (score 1):

Solution using [`df.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1.loc[df1['query'].isin(df2['query']),'new_col']='present'
df1.new_col=df1.new_col.fillna('Not_present')
print(df1)

  query target      new_col
0   A:1     AZ      present
1   B:4     AZ  Not_present
2   C:5     AZ      present
3   D:1     AZ      present
```

Comment: Hi, thanks you, It works as I wanter. But I just realized that in fact I will have to do it for several data frames. I just updated the post explain what is it really about. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

One other solution using `pd.merge`

```
df_temp = df_2.copy()
df_temp['new_col'] = 'present'
df_temp = df_temp['query', new_col]
df1 = df1.merge(df_temp, how='left', on='query').fillna('Not_present')
```